# optimise embedded link so useable across all browsers and web hosting platforms

Tags: html, css, wordpress, embedding

I've created an embedded link - containing my web app - so that people can paste it in-between the body tags of their HTML. Here's the embedded link:

```
<iframe src="http://insitu-app.com/index-tennis.html" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none"></iframe>
```

and here's an example result of it working:

http://insitu-app.com/examples/INsitu-embed-iframe.html

It works on Chrome, but the sliders and 3D models are missing on Internet Explorer and firefox. Furthermore, there are scrollbars present (which i do not want to be there ) that are not present in the original:

http://insitu-app.com/index-tennis.html

Lastly copying and pasting the embedded link into WYSIWYG platforms such as Wordpress doesn't work either -  do i need to create a plugin for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The scrollbar issue is addressed by Ronald's answer, but I can't reproduce the other problem: the website looks the same on all browsers (just the black screen with 3 icons, the middle of which brings up a popup).

Comment: I forgot to upload the JS file, sorry. it works now and appears to be working across all browsers. However how do i get it to work for Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding top: 0 and left: 0 to your iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://insitu-app.com/index-tennis.html" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none; top: 0; left: 0;"></iframe>
```

This will remove the scrollbars

Comment: Thanks can i add it within the embedded code? because it needs to contain the total solution

Comment: also in the first link there is white border over the top left and top. this is because of where it is positioned. It needs to be positioned centrally and without the white border?

Comment: Try adding top:0; and left:0; to your iframe element. Than you dont need to put margin:0 to your body tag

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: [can-i-put-an-iframe-on-a-wp-page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-put-an-iframe-on-a-wp-page) Looks like you need a plugin to embed iframes in Wordpress.. Hope this will help you with your Wordpress problem

Comment: Thanks Ronald, yes i should be able to figure it out from there